# Why does WordPress append a <li> bullet to my category tag?

Tags: categories

This is the code I am running on my index.php (blog page) which is very basic:

```
<p>Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> in <?php the_category(); ?></p>
```

Can anyone think why the category tag is printed with the HTML that I did NOT hardcode?

```
<ul class="post-categories">
<li> Category here for some reasons? </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2):

Read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/) for `the_category()`:

> Display category list for a post in either HTML list or custom format.

If the first argument isn't given, or is `''` then the categories will be output in a `<ul>`. To output them comma-separated, as an example, set the `$separator` to `', '`:

```
<?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
```

Every core function is documented in the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/). If a function isn't behaving as expected, check the documentation.